# How to customize the Page type model's IndexView - the listing view in Wagtail Admin

Tags: python, django, wagtail, modeladmin, wagtail-admin

I have multiple types of Page models in wagtail with parent page and subpages hierarchy. I want to customize the Index-view or the listing view to add more fields in all the pages under the main dashboard page in the Wagtail admin.

The Pages are registered by default to show in wagtail admin, can I write a method to overwrite the list of fields to show in index view or is there a way to overwrite the ModelAdmin for Page types and use list_display to add more fields?

Comment: Can any available hook(@hooks.register) add the additional fields to the listing view in Wagtail admin? or have to write own hook to do this?